# difference between integer and decimal literals

Tags: c++, integer, decimal, literals

```
85         // decimal
0213       // octal
0x4b       // hexadecimal
30         // int
30u        // unsigned int
30l        // long
30ul       // unsigned long
```

I'm new to C++. What's the difference between int (30) and decimal (85) in [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constants_literals.htm)?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy This sentence is in another section! It is about decimal floating-point literals. What does that have to do with this?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I thought the OP used the word "decimal" to describe a number with decimal places, not a base 10 integer.

Comment: Could you please ask a clear question, without resource to external links?

Comment: I don't know why this question getting so many downvotes. Seems a reasonable question to me.

Comment: I like how the tutorial introduces `#define` before `const` and doesn't even attempt to steer the reader away from using `#define`. Also, *An array name is a constant pointer to the first element of the array.* and *It is legal to use array names as constant pointers, and vice versa.* Please go find an actual [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). This isn't working.

Comment: @NeilKirk It was originally so poorly formatted that you would have been excused for thinking that the question was why `0213` was “decimal”. Bad formatting may be excusable for a first question, but people here have become allergic to low-quality questions because there are so many of them, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote :

```
85         // decimal
0213       // octal
0x4b       // hexadecimal
30         // int
30u        // unsigned int
30l        // long
30ul       // unsigned long
```

Here the three top lines show how to write a number's *value* in the desired base.
The four remaining lines describe suffixes to distinguish *types*.

`int` happens to have no suffix.

Answer (score 6):

The table you are reading [from the tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constants_literals.htm) is not clear. It should be represented as two tables:

Integer constants can be in one of three bases:

```
85         // decimal
0213       // octal
0x4b       // hexadecimal
```

They can have a suffix to indicate a minimum type rank and signedness:

```
30         // int
30u        // unsigned int
30l        // long
30ul       // unsigned long
```

You can write a hexadecimal long constant as `0x1234l`.

This would also be a good place in the tutorial to say that the suffixes `l` or `ll`, when used, only indicate a minimal type rank and that the integer constant will be attributed a wider type if it does not fit in the indicated type.

Comment: I'm not familliar with long and unsigned and unsigned long but if i got it right, 30 is also decimal?

Comment: @hanseN Yes, 30 is decimal because it does not have any `0` or `0x` prefix. The prefix (if any) indicates the base. No prefix indicates base 10.

Answer (score 2):

30 and 85 are both decimals and integers (type `int`). The two are not mutually exclusive.